# Store filename in variable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to store the filename that is copied in the following task into a variable and use that variable in a later task.

The filename will be something like: `my-archive.zip`. There will be only one `.zip` file being copied to the staging directory at this point.

Is there a way to do this?

This is being run in a MacOS pool.

Edit: The updated tasks in accord with the below answer.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'copy to staging'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: '*.zip'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'get archive file name'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      cd "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"
            $zipFile = dir | Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".zip"}
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=archiveName;]$zipFile.Name"
    failOnStderr: true
    pwsh: true

- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'publish to feed'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
    vstsFeedPublish: 'xyz'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: '$(archiveName)'
    versionOption: 'minor'
```

Comment: Hi, are you running that pipeline in Linux environment?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT This current script is running under MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a small PowerShell script:

```
- script: |
      cd "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"
      $zipFile = dir | Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".zip"}
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=zipFile;]$zipFile.Name"
```

After this task you can use the variable `zipFile` in the later tasks.

Comment: It seems when I try to use the variable, it outputs something like this: `@{Name=archive-name.zip}`. It is being used this like in a later task: `vstsFeedPackagePublish: '$(zipFile)'`

Comment: @rhughes I fixed it to `$zipFile.Name"`

Comment: With that change, the result is closer, but has the full path and `.Name` appended: `/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/a/archive-file.zip.Name` I have updated the question with more details if that can help.

Comment: Using `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName("$zipFile.Name")` has fixed the path issue. I'll remove the `.Name` manually, unless there is another way?

Comment: @rhughes In my case get only the name :/ anyway, thanks for your update!!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can also consider using [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) with script below if you're in **Linux/MacOS** environment:

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      WantedFile=$( find . -name "*.zip")
      BaseName=$(basename $WantedFile)
      FileName=$(echo $BaseName| cut -d . -f1)
      echo $FileName
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=archiveName]$FileName"
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

It works well on my side to get the pure FileName without file extension.